# Shorthand way of creating html elements from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Is there a way to make this into something shorter? I have a list of 15 questions and need them to stay in order. after each question is answered it go to a nextQuestion function. I would like to keep that as is. I've tried doing a for loop, but it keeps making the questions come out of order. Also, I'm very new to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function questionContent() {    
    $("#gameShow").append("<p><strong>" + 
        questions[questionTracker].question + 
        "</p><p class='choices'>" + 
        questions[questionTracker].choices[0] + 
        "</p><p class='choices'>" + 
        questions[questionTracker].choices[1] + 
        "</p><p class='choices'>" + 
        questions[questionTracker].choices[2] + 
        "</p><p class='choices'>" + 
        questions[questionTracker].choices[3] + 
        "</strong></p>");
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend not using `<strong>` as it is dependent on implementation, which is **not** making it bold, but marking the inner elements as *important*.  If the soul purpose is to make them bold use a css class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear to me how your array of questions is put together, but your function looks like it is intended to take a single question and create the html for that question along with an array of answer choices.

To simplify the function in your question, you can handle the first `question` property and then loop through the `choices` array to add the rest of the html you are looking to append. Something like the example below (left out your `strong` tags cause they seem oddly placed and I wasn't sure where you really wanted them).

You could loop through your main questions array and call this function (or just create a single function to do it all) but hard to say exactly how you should handle that without more code or data in your example.

```
function questionContent(questions) {
  let question = `<p>${questions[questionTracker].question}</p>`;
  for (const choice of questions[questionTracker].choices) {
    question += `<p class="choices">${choice}</p>`;
  }

  $("#gameShow").append(question);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you. I tried something like that, but I didn't set up a variable for question or put questions in the questionContent() lol. Thanks for your help!